# Pin button to left while transformed

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create this `<a>` element that pins left of the screen. Its position is absolute but I cannot get it as in image:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a class="feedback__btn">Feedback</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.feedback__btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
```

Two things that cause the tag from not pinning to the left: transform and the width/height. How to to get it pinned to either sides of screen (left in this case) with the same transformation?

Comment: why absolute, these must be fixed otherwise if you scroll it will change position accordingly. let me know if you want that css

Comment: Correct. But making it fixed does not solve the problem ;)

Comment: left: -51px will do your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the center-point of the button, with transform:translateX(-50%) you will have a much easier way to figure out how much you need to move the button to place it correctly:

```
.feedback__btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 23px;
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 46px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(270deg);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
```

I have added `transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(270deg);` and `left: 23px;` to your code and changed the heigh of the button to an even number, as that is easier to halve (half of 46 is 23, while half of 45 is 22.5, and you can't have half pixels).

I have also changed the position to fixed, so it follows the user down the site when scrolling.

Comment: That would work and also `transform-origin: top left;` Thanks